# Did Kareena Kapoor charge Aamir Khan for talking to her?

Tags: plot-explanation, talaash

In the 2012 Hindi movie, [Talaash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talaash_%282012_film%29), Did Rosie charge Surjan Singh for the endless talking by the river side he did for a few days? After-all, she was a 'fancy lady'. Also, Surjan Singh must have become suspicious if she didn't.

Another Question, Why did Rosie spent so much time with Surjan Singh at all? She could have got her revenge without doing it.

Comment: Ghost doesn't need money, so Rosie(kareena kapoor) doesnot need to charge him. :P

Comment: @AnkitSharma But not charging must have rose the suspension of Aamir. She was acting like a human

Comment: Its bollywood masala film......which mostly doesnot have any good explanations.

Comment: @AnkitSharma yet you can enjoy the movie with a fantasy mind :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were no proofs of charging Surjan by Rosie. She acted to Surjan like she wanted to help him because she liked him(or maybe she tried to seduce him so that he finally accepts to sleep with her!) and also wanted to finish the bad things happening around the red light area.

Rosie spent too much time with him and it is also true that she could get her revenge without helping him. But she wanted not only to kill them but also to show the world what they did to her and why did such accidents occur and they deserved death sentence. At last everybody including Surjan came to know what they did. This is what she wanted.

Another point also to be considered that like Frenny told "Dissatisfied souls seek other dissatisfied souls(whether living or dead)". Surjan was in pain, so maybe she thought of helping him as he was in pain due to his sons sudden death. After all till the end of the movie it is evident Surjan started believing in ghosts.